# What can I do to trace what a program does, not having the source code and the support from the program supplier

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiler, trace

I have now to deal with a program called [FDT](http://fdt.se/) whose support is no longer taken by the company I am working for but still using the same program. Now I need to insert new orders into the program from the site which I can get in `xml`, `csv` or some other from `magento`. I am trying to automate this process. All work in the office are done on the basis of this software FDT like checking the out of stock, bills printing and others.

I am now thinking to use `profiler` to trace events. I would like to know what processing does the program do when we place some order in it. I am not a good user of Profiler, I would like some suggestions if it is possible know what tables it effects, what columns it updates or writes to.

Above it is a new order no. the program generates. which is a unique id and is integer. I am not able to know the pattern. I do have a test server where I can make changes and trial and error is no problem.

Some suggestions on how shall I proceed or at least start going on would be appreciated.

I think most important would be to trace the `T-sql` but again which events and what filter to use?
I am sorry if it a stupid question, I am trying to learn .. source code and support is not an option.

Comment: Realistically there is no way to do this. Even if you trace the SQL using SQL Profiler, you won't know what processing is happening in the application code itself. It sounds like the program is some sort of ERP or Accounting package, and those are very dangerous things to mess with because any issues or mistakes with financial data can cause huge legal and audit problems. The real solution is to get support; if you buy an application you have to include the future costs of support and maintenance in your planning.

Comment: @Pondlife      Thanks for response, I am a new starter, the organization do not want any support having it expensive or some conflict I never know. I am able to find out the table it stores those info. running profiler as well as trial and error in test server. Hope to make it working. I got to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has too many parts- how to do trace, how to deal with an application post-support-contract, how to reverse engineer an app and even if that is a good idea (and sometimes it's the only idea available) I'd re-ask this as a series of narrow technical question or ask it on Programmers (after reading their FAQ they only like certain questions)

Yup, been there done that. In large organizations, normally these tasks fall to technies who don't weild the awesome power of the budget and can't personal go negotiate a new contract with the original vendor. I assume you have food bills to pay and can't tell your supervisor, "well, I ain't do doing nothing until we get a support contract"

Step 0 Diagram the tables - work out the entity relationships and assembly a data dictionary (one that explains the motivation of each table and column, not just the name and data type)

Step 1 Attach the profiler to an active instance of SQL 2008.  If you have a specific question about SQL Profiler, open a new question. One hint-- if you are attached to a multi-user instance, filter down to just your own user (the one in the connection string) 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/

Step 2 
Do an action in the application and watch what SQL was emitted. If it is SQL, you can copy and paste it to Management studio so you can diagram the query and run your own test executions.  If it is a stored proc, you go read the source code of the stored procedure. If the stored procedure is encrypted, it may or may not be possible to decrypt it. Scenarios when decrypting the code is fairly defensible is when you aren't redistributing it and the supporting company isn't there.

Step 3
Once you understand the app, you can write reports, or more likey, you want to record either new transactions or old transactions differently.

If the app is written in .net or java, you can decompile it and read the code. Creating a custom build from that source isn't going to be fun.  A more likely thing to happen is you will create an application that targets the same tables or possibly export all the data out of the original app and into a new bespoke one.

Comment: Thanks now I know I am in the right track. Never know about encrypted stored procedures, never had seen or heard, hope I will find somewhere here. Yes there are some stored procedures and some odd looking procedures called. How do I know if the program are written in .Net or in Java? If they are written in those.